# C-2d array print function not working when I call it in main function

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote two functions, readMatrix which allocate a double pointer and take the input from keyboard and the second function is a print function.

When I call the print function in main function, it does not work completely.

This is the code :

```
void print(int** mat, int lin, int col) {
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix is:\n");
    for(i=0; i<lin; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(mat+i)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int** readMatrix(int** mat, int lin, int col) {
    int x;
    int i,j;
    mat==(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));
    for(x=0; x<lin; x++) {
        mat[x]=(int*)malloc(col*sizeof(int));
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<lin; i++) {
        printf("Line %d: ", i);
        for(j=0; j<col; j++) {
            scanf("%d",  &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int lin, col;
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter number of lines: ");
    scanf("%d", &lin);
    printf("Enter number of cols: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    int** mat = readMatrix(mat,lin,col);
    print(mat,lin,col);
    return 0;
}
```

After I take the input, I get the message "Matrix is" but the matrix does not appear, why?

If I call the print function inside readMatrix function, it works, but why is not working if I call it in main?

Thanks.

Comment: regarding: `mat==(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));` and similar statements:  1) the returned type (in C) is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  2) for robust code, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter mat is not used in the function `readMatrix` because its value id overwritten

```
int** readMatrix(int** mat, int lin, int col) {
    int x;
    int i,j;
    mat==(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));
    //...
```

Moreover the function returns nothing though its return type is not void.

So this record

```
int** mat = readMatrix(mat,lin,col);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You need to declare the function at  least lie

```
int** readMatrix( int lin, int col);
```

and at the end of the function to write

```
return mat;
```

For example

```
int** readMatrix(int lin, int col) {
    int **mat==(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));
    //...

    return mat;
}
```

And the function will be called like

```
int** mat = readMatrix(lin,col);
```

Also in main you should free the all allocated memory when the arrays is not needed any more.

For example

```
for ( i = 0; i < lin; i++ )
{
    free( mat[i] );
}

free( mat );
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to return the matrix. So I should remove the mat from the list parameter and I should declare the int** mat = .... inside the function, right? I wanted to do this but I read that if I return a local variable, like **mat, when I call the function, that mat it shouldn t be destroyed? like the normal variables?

Comment: I did how you said and it's working, thanks! But I still wonder about returning a local variable. What's the difference if I return a local variable (which I know is not allowed) and returning a pointer?

Comment: @ValiRO what you else need is to free the all allocated memory in main.

Comment: Yes, thank you:)

Comment: @ValiRO The function returns a copy of the value of the pointer that is assigned to the variable mat in main. The allocated memory in the heap still valid.

Comment: Thank you, I got it:)

Answer (score 1):

`readMatrix` takes `mat` as a parameter, but that is useless because it only receives the value of it, and it does not have a value yet. (To be able to change a variable in the calling routine, a routine must receive a pointer to it, not its value.)

`readMatrix` is declared to return `int **` but does not have a `return` statement.

`mat==(int**)malloc(lin*sizeof(int*));` uses `==`, which compares values. It does not perform an assignment.

Remove the `mat` parameter from the declaration of `readMatrix`. Remove the `mat` argument from the call to `readMatrix`. Correct the `==` to `=`. Add a `return` statement that returns the value of `mat` from the allocation that was performed in `readMatrix`.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to return the matrix. So I should remove the mat from the list parameter and I should declare the int** mat = .... inside the function, right? I wanted to do this but I read that if I return a local variable, like **mat, when I call the function, that mat it shouldn t be destroyed? like the normal variables?

Comment: I did how you said and it's working, thanks! But I still wonder about returning a local variable. What's the difference if I return a local variable (which I know is not allowed) and returning a pointer?

Comment: @ValiRO: You can return the value of a local variable. You should not return the address of a local automatic variable. Once you know the value of a variable, you know the value, so the value is safe to return. But, when you know the address of a variable, it only has that address during its lifetime. When a function returns, the lifetimes of its local automatic variables end, and their former addresses become invalid.